# how to convert decimal value to binary bits?

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, decimal

Basically I want to learn the algorithm on how to convert decimal to binary, I found this:

```
int convert(int dec)
{
    if (dec == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2));
    }
}
```

It works just fine, but I am not able to understand `dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2)`. Can you please convert this in an understandable way for people with basic math? e.g. what method is performed first and how does the binary  `dec = 50` turns to `110010`?

FYI: I can do it, this way: `50=(2^5=32)+(2^4=16)+(2^1)=50`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not converting to binary, it is converting to decimal which *looks* like binary. And yes, it is using recursion.

Comment: (ec) Beware of this code.  This code is teaching you a very confusing, ultimately wrong lesson.  This code appears to convert, for example, the decimal number 5 into the decimal number 101.  That sort of *looks* like decimal-to-binary conversion, but it's not.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for informing me on about that, can you please redirect me to a proper lesson or what algorithm does computers use to convert decimal to binary?

Comment: It would probably make the most sense to walk through the code for some example input (either using a debugger or by hand).

Comment: @aaaa I was going to say, "Why not try a Google search", but I tried it myself, and the very first hit was (I guess not surprisingly) the very same broken code you posted.

Comment: @aaaa There are probably thousands of better examples scattered across the net, but I don't think I have a handle just now on one I like.

Comment: `1101011 % 2 = 1`. `1101011 / 2 = 110101`. `10*1234 + 5 = 12345`. The code is a bit confusing, but it shouldn't be too hard to see what's going on here by just looking at the results you get when performing those operations.

Comment: Possibly not a duplicate of [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format) but there is much there of relevance.

Comment: An integer is already stored in a binary format. What (I think) you're really asking is how to print it as a string of ones and zeroes

Comment: @TimRandall, `Basically I want to learn the algorithm on how to convert decimal to binary` what is so confusing about that?

Comment: Then leave C alone and look for a pen-and-paper method. It is very same one, but decoupled from programming.

Comment: @EugeneSh. did I say I need a c program to convert dec to bin? I said an algorithm to convert dec to bin? FYI: I have remove `c` tag.

Comment: I have provided the algorithm as requested. Apologies if you got the impression that I was confused. I was, perhaps, under a similar misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't implement it for you, but I am happy to describe the algorithm and give an example.

Converting from base 10 to base `b` ultimately follows the same series of steps which includes repeatedly dividing by `b` then saving the remainder.

An example of what this looks like for 50 (base10) to base2 would be:

```
          Quotient  Remainder  
----------------------------
50 / 2 =  25        0
25 / 2 =  12        1
12 / 2 =   6        0
 6 / 2 =   3        0
 3 / 2 =   1        1 
 1 / 2 =   0        1
```

Examining the remainders in reverse (bottom to top) gives your the correct representation in base `b` (2 in this case): `110010`

For information on *why* this works, take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/converting-decimalbase-10-numbers-to-binary-by-repeatedly-dividing-by-2

Comment: Thanks that almost answered my question, Just need to know what algorithm does machines use to convert dec to bin or vice versa?

Comment: Machines don't need to convert anything, they store binary and work with binary.

Comment: @EugeneSh. okay so let's say someone on his keyboard pressed `A` which is registered as decimal # `41` then how does computer know `41` is `101001` and need to perform Functions for character `A`?

Comment: *which is registered as decimal # 41* - it is not. It is registered as a number, which if represented as decimal, will look like `41`, or if is represented as binary will look as `101001`, or if represented as hexadecimal, will look as `0x29`...

Comment: @aaaa That seems like a harsh, especially considering that everything EugeneSh said is correct. What we see as characters typed on a keyboard your computer sees as numbers.

Comment: @aaaa also, typically when you ask for help on the internet it pays off to not be rude to the people attempting to help you

Comment: The computer naturally works with binary numbers. That's why we refer to processors as 32-bit, 64-bit, etc. We are literally referring to the number of binary digits that the processor can handle in its registers. When you press 'A' on your keyboard, the machine might receive a scan code 00011110 which is written in hex as 0x1e or in decimal as 30. But the machine sees those eight bits - those eight binary digits - not any other representation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at `dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2)`. The first part `dec % 2` is a modulo operation, and this is what decides if a digit should be 1 or 0. The rest, `10 * convert(dec / 2)` finds the next (and next and next recursively) digit and puts it on the left of the current digit.

You could quite easily see what is going on by slightly modifying your code. Change the `else` to:

```
else
{
    int ret = (dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2));
    printf("%d %d\n", dec, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

and then `convert(50)` will print this:

```
$ ./a.out 
1 1
3 11
6 110
12 1100
25 11001
50 110010
```

But as pointed out in the comments, this is not a real base conversion. You have converted the number 50 to a completely different number that *looks* like the binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

**An algorithm** that will, given an integer N, produce a string of characters S representing N in binary notation.

```
do
{
    if N is odd
    {
        add '1' to the beginning of S
    }
    else
    {
        add '0' to the beginning of S
    }
    divide N by 2
}
while N is non-zero
```

Using the requested example:

```
initially N=50 and S is empty
50 is even: S="0"
divide N by 2: N=25
25 is odd: S="10"
divide N by 2: N=12
12 is even: S="010"
divide N by 2: N=6
6 is even: S="0010"
divide N by 2: N=3
3 is odd: S="10010"
divide N by 2: N=1
1 is odd: S="110010"
divide N by 2: N=0
stop looping
```